# Preventing properties from being observable in Breeze.js

Tags: knockout.js, odata, breeze

I use Knockout.js with Breeze.js to communicate with OData services. In response array I receive all properties are observable. But it's not what I want.
Does someone know is there any way to prevent Breeze.js from making all properties observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Breeze 1.4.6, there is now a 'noTracking' method on the EntityQuery that should do what you are asking for.

See the release notes for 1.4.6 for more info: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download

Comment: How could we live without this feature :)